# Linkedin API repost (Instant delivery) without creating a new post with the original post attached

Tags: linkedin-api

How to use the Linkedin API to create a repost similar to creating one through the Linkedin menu (highlighted in gray in the image). [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-%20api?view=li-lms-2023-03&tabs=http#reshare-a-post) describes only the creation of a repost with the original post attached (as when creating from the Linkedin menu - the first item in the image)

API version: 032023

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @EdieW. No, I haven't found a solution